# Shutdown OSX from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, remote

How can I shut down an iMac (OSX 10.6.8) on my wireless network wirelessly from my Windows 7 laptop?

There are a few questions on this site for shutting down Windows *from OSX*, but I want it the other way.

I've tried the `shutdown -i` command on my computer, but that doesn't work, so I'm guessing that only works for Windows to Windows computers (although I can't find anything online to support this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable remote login in `Sharing` in System Preferences on your Mac. Then you can use ssh to login and enter this terminal command: `sudo shutdown`.

There are free ssh tools available for windows, for example [PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/) (it's free).